# Error message in emmeans function output in Shiny : "object 'factor' not found"

Tags: r, shiny, anova, shiny-reactivity, emmeans

I am very new shiny user. I wanted to show the results of post-hoc test using emmeans function. Here's the code of my shiny app.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Statistical analyses "),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # select variable/factors
      
      selectInput("Depedent_Var", "Select your y : the dependent variable",
                  choices = c("length_ch2","total_count_ch2")),
      selectInput("factor1", "Select the first factor",selected = "Vector",
                  choices = c("Vector","Time")),
      selectInput("factor2", "Select the second factor",selected = "Time",
                  choices = c("Vector","Time")),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Statistical test : Anova", tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Significance of the main effects",DT::dataTableOutput("ANOVA")),
                    tabPanel("Tukey's post hoc tests 1",DT::dataTableOutput("Tukey1"))))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

server.r

```
    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      
      data <- reactive({Neurite_all_no})    
    
      output$ANOVA<-DT::renderDataTable({
        
        if (input$Depedent_Var=="length_ch2") {
          LM.fit<-lm(sqrt(get(input$Depedent_Var))~get(input$factor1)*get(input$factor2),data=data())
          
          Anovaa=(Anova(LM.fit))
          rownames(Anovaa)<-c(input$factor1,input$factor2,paste0(input$factor1,":",input$factor2),"inter")
          DT::datatable(data.frame(Anovaa)[-4,])%>% 
            formatRound(columns =1:length(Anovaa[1,]),digits = 2)
        }
      })
      
      output$Tukey1<-DT::renderDataTable({
        
        if (input$Depedent_Var=="length_ch2") {
          LM.fit<-lm(sqrt(get(input$Depedent_Var))~get(input$factor1)*get(input$factor2),data=data())
          em<-emmeans(LM.fit,~get(input$factor2)|get(input$factor1),type="response")
          aa=pairs(regrid(em),adjust="bonferroni")
          DT::datatable(data.frame(aa))
        }
      })
    })
    
    ################################################################################
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The shiny app:

all good for the first tab, but I get this error using emmeans function:

[image]

**Why does the function emmeans is not recognizing my "Vector" factor?**

Comment: It could be helpful to have some sample data to test this on if possible?

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry.  But a piece of advice - try to move code that does computations outside of shiny into an .R file that the Shiny app sources.  It makes it much easier to test and debug.  Best to keep the Shiny app purely for the app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this change to the `if` statement inside your `output$Tukey1`. Basically, I suggest building up the formulae, used in the `lm()` and the `emmeans()` calls

```
if (input$Depedent_Var=="length_ch2") {
  lm_formula = as.formula(paste0("sqrt(",input$Depedent_Var,")~",input$factor1,"*", input$factor2))
  LM.fit<-lm(lm_formula,data=data())
  
  em_formula = as.formula(paste0("~",input$factor2,"|", input$factor1))
  em<-emmeans(LM.fit,em_formula,type="response")
  
  aa=pairs(regrid(em),adjust="bonferroni")
  DT::datatable(data.frame(aa))
}
```

Comment: Also, emmeans does not *need* a formula, you can just give the names of the factors, i.e., `emmeans(LM.fit, input$factor2, by = input$factor1)`

Comment: Thank you !! it works. Out of curiosity why do we need to build the formula, via paste0, for it to work?

Comment: Try looking the object returned from `lm()`, when doing something like this: `dep = "y"; ind = "x"; lm(get(dep)~get(ind), data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=rnorm(3)))`. Notice the names of the coefficients

Comment: Now, compare that to building the formula: `dep = "y"; ind = "x"; lm(as.formula(paste(dep,"~", ind)), data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=rnorm(3)))`

Comment: Oh I see ! the name of the coefficient is not "x" like it should it's "get(ind)". Thank you for the clear explanation !